# Buggy Regexp Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I've inserted a document with a `raw_id` field equal to `1.2.3.04ABC`, and I'm trying to construct a regular expression query to search the document in ES. I'm using the following query:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "raw_id": "1\\.2\\.3\\.04ABC" 
        }
    }
}'
```

This returns the result empty result

```
{
    "took":1,
    "timed_out":false,
    "_shards": {
        "total":5,
        "successful":5,
        "failed":0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total":0,
        "max_score":null,
        "hits":[]
    }
}
```

On the other hand, when I use the slightly modified query

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "raw_id": "1\\.2\\.3.*" 
        }
    }
}'
```

I get the nonempty result:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "adfafadfafa",
                "_index": "hello",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "raw_id": "1.2.3.04ABC"
                },
                "_type": "world"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "total": 1
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 2
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why the first query doesn't work?

Comment: Not gonna lie, according to the docs that should work. Only thing I can think of is regex indexing isn't enabled for `raw_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `raw_id` field is an analyzed string, while it should be `not_analyzed`. I've used the following mapping with one analyzed string field `id` and another `not_analyzed` string field `raw_id`:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/hello' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "world": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "raw_id": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then I've indexed the following document:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/1' -d '{
  "id": "1.2.3.04ABC",
  "raw_id": "1.2.3.04ABC"
}'
```

Now taking your query above, if I search against the `id` field, I get no hits:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "id": "1\\.2\\.3\\.04ABC" 
        }
    }
}'
=> 0 hits KO
```

However, I do get one hit when I search against the `raw_id` field:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "raw_id": "1\\.2\\.3\\.04ABC" 
        }
    }
}'
=> 1 hit OK
```

With your second query I get a hit with each field:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "id": "1\\.2\\.3.*" 
        }
    }
}'
=> 1 hit OK

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hello/world/_search' -d '{
"query": {
    "regexp": {
        "raw_id": "1\\.2\\.3.*" 
        }
    }
}'
=> 1 hit OK
```